# Is my answer the same as the solution? [Linear Maps]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I am trying this question on *Linear Algebra Done Right*:
[image]

In the solution, it said "Let $(w_1,...,w_m)$ be a basis of $W$" and do the work following.

My trial was

Suppose $T$ is surjective, prove $TS$ is an identity map on $W$.
Let $w \in W$ and $v \in V$

$TS(w) = T(v) = w$

Then I said $TS$ is an identity map. I feel that it may be wrong. But I am not sure if this is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not the same as the solution because your answer doesn't solve the problem at all. You take a $w\in W$ and a $v\in V$ and you claim that $TS(w)=T(v)=w$ without explaining why would any of these equalities holds. Hint: in general, they don't.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you never say what $S$ is. So your solution isn't wrong in the sense that you haven't said anything that's wrong. But it's not right either because you haven't shown that $S$ exists (which is the whole point of the problem).

The issue for this problem is that it's tempting to define $S(w) = v$ if $T(v) = w$. However, this is only well defined if there is only one $v$ such that $T(v) = w$. If $T(v) = w$ and $T(v') = w$, you need $S$ to decide between $S(w) = v$ or $S(w) = v'$ and you need to be able to make this choice for all $w \in W$.

Comment: is the sentence, "Because $T$ is surjective, for each $j$ there exists $v_j \in V$ such that $w_j = Tv_j$" the same as what you say "if there is only one $v$ such that $T(v) = w$?

Comment: @JOHN In general, the set $\{v : T(v) = w\}$ is non-empty (because $T$ is surjective) and if $v_0 \in \{v : T(v) = w\}$ then $\{v : T(v) = w\} = \{v_0 + v_1 : v_1 \in \ker T\}$. Meaning if $v_0$ is a particular solution to $T(v) = w$, then every solution is of the form $v_0 + v_1$ for some $v_1$ in the kernel (= nullspace) of $T$. So this is what you do. You find a particular solution for each basis vector $w_j$ and this allows you to write each solution set in the form of (particular solution) + (any element of the nullspace).